# Mod.IO get mod file as base64 (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, download, fetch-api, game-development

I'm writing a mod.io api for my game and I want to be able to grab the zip folder for the mods download from the download URL but from what I've researched I can't find anything about this topic.
On the website I have this file [The file on the test.mod.io website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1zoU.png)

I also have managed to get the download link for the mod which looks like this
`https://api.test.mod.io/v1/games/{My Game's ID}/mods/{The Mod's ID}/files/{The file's ID}/download`
from the api using promises.

I've tried fetching towards the url and using the xmlhttprequest class but nothing has been successful in gathering the files data.
I tried getting the files data in base64 by using a filereader class and so on but to no avail.
When I go to the url the file downloads automatically so I think the file is stored on another server that I can't directly access through the api.